# React - Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, npm, package

I decided to install the npm package [react-radio-buttons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-radio-buttons) after installing and applying on my component gives an error:

> ```
> ./node_modules/react-radio-buttons/index.jsx 80:6
> module parse failed: Unexpected token (80:6)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> |     const style = horizontal ? { display: 'inline-flex', width: '100%' } : {};
> |     return (
> >       <div style={style} { ...props}>
> |         {
> |           children.map((c, i) => this.renderChild(c, i, i === checkedIndex)))
> ```

I suppose the problem may be related to `package.json` but I don't know how to solve the problem. Before I provide the package file, I want to warn a lot of properties inside the `dependencies` object, I will cut everything out and leave only `"react-radio-buttons": "^ 1.2.2",` the actual package behind which the error occurs.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react-radio-buttons": "^1.2.2",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the error was caused by incorrect usage =>  `import { RadioGroup } from "react-radio-buttons/index";`  (`/index`  should be removed)

the solution was to change it to:

```
import { RadioGroup } from "react-radio-buttons";
```